# Dell Touchpad not working + cursor invisable

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, dell-inspiron

I just brought dell inspiron 15 3000 series laptop with Ubuntu and installed windows 8.

For some reasons it does not show mouse cursor. during installation it doesn't show cursor and after installation it is not showing cursor at all.

I installed dell touch pad drivers with all other important chipset drivers but still cursor disappear.

Strange thing is, when i plugin external mouse then cursor appears and when i remove external mouse then again cursor disappear magically.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Check if the internal mouse pad is disabled. But invariably the cursor should appear...

Comment: yes cursor should appear. That's the most strange thing!

Comment: Dell uses in laptops pointing device that is not supported natively by Windows? Seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed Windows 8.1 yourself, you need to go to Dell's support site and manually install all the additional drivers and utilities including, in all likelihood, the Dell Touchpad Utility.

Go to support.dell.com, enter your Service Tag and then your OS. You should get a list of drivers and utilities to install.

Comment: i know it already!